# Show that the following matrix has $4$ as an eigen value of multiplicity $3$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Show that the following matrix has $4$ as an eigen value of multiplicity $3$

$\begin{bmatrix} 5&1&1&1&1&1\\1&5&1&1&1&1\\1&1&5&1&1&1\\1&1&1&4&0&1\\1&1&1&0&3&0\\1&1&1&1&0&4\end{bmatrix}$.

How should I try this?Isn't this equivalent to finding the entire spectrum of the above matrix?

Or there are some tricks involved here?Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call the matrix $A$. It is real symmetric, hence diagonalisable. Therefore, it suffices to show that the rank deficiency of $A-4I$ is $3$.

Comment: What is rank deficiency? Do you mean $Rank(A-4I)=3$ i.e dimension of image space of $A-4I$

Comment: @RishabhPant The rank deficiency of a square matrix is the difference between the vector space's dimension and the matrix's rank. E.g. the rank deficiencies of invertible matrices are always zero and the rank deficiency of the zero matrix is precisely the dimension of the vector space.

Answer (score -1):

Hint:$A=\begin{bmatrix}
4 & 0 & 0 &0&0&0\\
0&4&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&4&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&3&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&2&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&3
\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 &1&1&1\\
1 & 1 & 1 &1&1&1\\
1 & 1 & 1 &1&1&1\\
1 & 1 & 1 &1&1&1\\
1 & 1 & 1 &1&1&1\\
1 & 1 & 1 &1&1&1
\end{bmatrix}$
$$\text{Both matrices commute, eigenvalues for the first are} ~~4,4,4,3,2,3$$
$$\text{eigenvalues for thesecond matrix are}~~0,0,0,0,0,6$$

Comment: not correct, there are some zeros in the original matrix

Comment: It's incorrect;you missed the entries